# SQLITE check if id has certain value

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLITE table like this:

```
id      key      value
244574  16       999
244574  18       999
244574  54       174
214808  16       662
214808  17       808
214808  33       1
214808  60       2
214809  16       902 
214809  17       1103
214809  33       1
214809  60       2
218965  19       808
218965  21       662
218965  33       1
218965  60       8
218966  19       1103
218966  21       902
218966  33       1
218966  60       8
```

Fiddle: [click here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dZiNrEgY3wf9smyJdnxJ3S/1)

Now I try to get a list of IDs where the key is not 60 OR key is 60 and value = 8. When I do a simple:

```
select * from items_attributes where (key != 60) OR (key = 60 AND value = 8);
```

I ofc get those rows where key is not 60. But I only want to get three rows as result:

```
id      key           value
244574  [16;18;54]    [999;999;174]
218965  [19;21;33;60] [808;662;1;8]
218966  [19;21;33;60] [1103;902;1;8]
```

Since I'm a beginner when it comes to SQL I can just think of a solution with concat but I have no clue tbh. Maybe someone is able to help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
select 
    id,
    '[' || group_concat(key, ';') || ']',
    '[' || group_concat(value, ';') || ']'
from items_attributes
group by id
having 
    -- no rows with key 60 for this id
    count(case when key = 60 then 1 end) = 0 
or 
    -- 1 or more rows with key 60 & value 8 for this id
    count(case when key = 60 and value = 8 then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how you want to get just three rows. However, the following query :-

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    '['||group_concat(key,';')||']' AS key_group, 
    '['||group_concat(value,';')||']' AS value_group
FROM items_attributes 
WHERE (key != 60) OR (key = 60 AND value = 8) 
GROUP BY id;
```

Results in :-

[image]

I understand now. This would appear to do what you wish:-

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    '['||group_concat(key,';')||']' AS key, 
    '['||group_concat(value,';')||']' AS value 
FROM items_attributes WHERE id NOT IN(
    SELECT id FROM items_attributes WHERE (key = 60 AND value != 8))
GROUP by id ORDER BY id DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. This looks quite good. But There are still the IDs which have the key 60 with a value != 8. So the first two rows should not be returned.